# Preg_Match Syntax

Tags: php, regex, syntax, preg-match

How might you use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to detect any text characters in a string?

Comment: What do you consider a text character?

Comment: a-z or A-Z. sorry should have specified.

Comment: Just a note, http://www.regular-expressions.info/  is a great resource for regex syntax etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
if(preg_match('/[a-z]/i',$input)) {
     echo $input,' has a text character';
}
```

The regex used: `[a-z]` is a character class which matches the lowercase characters. 
We also use the `i` modifier to make the match case insensitive effectively making `[a-z]` match both the lowercase and uppercase characters.

Comment: No, that's not any of the lowercase letters: it's just a-z; é is a lowercase letter, and so is ß; ﬃ and  ĳ  and œ, too. Also  ª and µ, amongst many, *many* others.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
preg_match('/[a-z]/i', 'hi test string');
```

for example

```
var_dump(preg_match('/[a-z]/i', 'hi'));   # gives 1
var_dump(preg_match('/[a-z]/i', '1'));    # gives 0 as false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to detect if they're there?

```
preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $subject, $matches_arr);
```

That should do the trick.